# Angular $http caching woes

Tags: angularjs, http, caching

I have followed the documentation to the letter regarding caching in an $http get request. However, when I check in Fiddler, the request is still being made to the server. I also notice the lag in the UI while the request is being made.

What am I missing? I don't have to initialise the cache in any way do I?

Here is a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
$scope.loadData = function() {
    $scope.promise = $q.all([
            $http({
                url: '/api/brokers',
                method: 'GET',
                cache: true })
            .success(function (data) { $scope.enquiriesBrokers = data; }),

            $http({
                url: '/api/aircraft',
                method: 'GET',
                cache: true })
            .success(function(data) { $scope.aircraftTypes = data; })
        ]);
};
```

The code is still retrieving the data, but it doesn't appear that the cache is functioning. Any ideas?

Comment: You can check to see if Fiddler is caching the request by right clicking the URL in the fiddler and clicking properties.  There you can look for caching information under `WININET CACHE INFO`.  If there is cached data, then Fiddler might be making it appear as if it's actually flowing through to the server.  Does Fiddler's behavior match your browser's behavior?

Comment: @DavidL angular uses internal cache so ideally no new  request should show up on network

Comment: to be clear...first time in new page session the request is made to server ( as it should be) and subsequent requests in same session are also  sent? Just trying to make sure you aren't expecting browser cached data on page load from this config

Comment: I didn't really understand the second sentence of your question @charlietfl but yes: the request is happening as expected on the first execution but then being called again when it ought to be cached. I am writing an SPA so perhaps that is a problem?

Comment: SPA is what allows angular to do the caching internally, so that definitely isn't a problem. Can you create plunker demo that replicates this?

Comment: One idea might be to change to `$http.get( url, {cache:true})`. Also not sure why you aren't resolving the `$q.all` to pass data to scope. The way your code is written `$q.all` isn't doing anything

Comment: I'm afraid I can't create a plunker demo without a lot of effort and without exposing secret. The $q.all() is being used elsewehete in the code. I'm going to try refactoring as you suggest.

Comment: I have refactored but the problem remains. Maybe I should write a custom cache service.